# Submit multiple forms to other sites on a single click. (It does not support AJAX.)

Tags: jquery, forms, multiple-forms

I have been using jQuery to submit multiple forms by using this function:

```
<script>
    var submitted = "";
    function submitAllForms() {               

        var i=0;

        $("form").each(function () {

               submitted +=  $(this).submit();
               alert("submitted:"+i);

              i++;  
        });
    }

</script>';
```

But, this does not submit to all. It submits and posts data to only one site. In other words, only one form is being posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***ANSWER UPDATE***

According to the comment:

> It worked on Firefox but doesn't work on Google Chrome

This issue is related to the dom ready event. This doesn't work in firefox. I tested the changed snippet  with the last versions of Chrome, FF, Edge, IE. Only for FF I needed to use the event load instead of ready.

A possible solution can be based on ***IFRAMES*** (if you can use them):

- use a unique button to submit all forms
- insert or create a div container with no visiblity
- for each form insert into the previous div an iframe
- add to such an iframe the content of the corresponding form with updated data
- submit each form inside the corresponding iframe
- take care to empty the container...

The snippet:

```js
function onIframeReady(doc, html) {
  doc.find('body').append(html);
  //
  // if it's needed to change the action atr use:
  // doc.find('form').attr('action', 'new ac');
  //
  doc.find('form').submit();
}

$(function () {
  $('#submitMoreForms').on('click', function(e){
    $('#frmWrapper').empty();
    $('form').each(function(idx, ele){
      $(ele).find(':input').each(function(index, element) {
        if (element.type == 'textarea') {
          $(element).text($(element).val());
        } else {
          $(element).attr('value', $(element).val());
        }
      });

      $('<iframe>', {
        id:  'frm' + idx
      }).appendTo('#frmWrapper').ready(function() {
        if (window.mozInnerScreenX == null) {  // if not firefox
          onIframeReady($('#frm' + idx).contents(), ele.outerHTML);
        }
      }).one('load', function(e) {
        if (window.mozInnerScreenX != null) { // if firefox
          onIframeReady($('#frm' + idx).contents(), ele.outerHTML);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="action1" method="post">
  FORM1:<br/>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car
</form>
<form action="action2" method="post">
  FORM2:<br/>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
</form>
<form action="action3" method="post">
  FORM3:<br/>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
</form>

<input id="submitMoreForms" type="button" value="Submit More Forms" />
<div id="frmWrapper" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: It worked on Firefox but doesn't work on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can not submit multiple forms on one page this way. It will always submit the first form it encounters, because after submitting the form the page will refresh (post). This kind of stuff has to be done with AJAX or a JavaScript HTTPrequest.

There is one option you could try and that is setting the target of the form to blank, so on submit it will open a new tab or browser window. That way you can submit all forms. I do have to warn you for this if you want to use it in a application used by other users than yourself, because most browsers will block the popups created by the form submit.